# Angular 2 - Is it possible to build and deploy application modules individually

Tags: angular, structure, angular2-routing

We are working to achieve a structure with Angular 2 and trying to decide whether Angular 2 is the right solution for us or not.

Let's assume;

- There is one application just including a side navigation menu, a header and a container.
- There are a hundred pages in the project (every pages contain huge business forms). And each of these forms are separate modules.
- There are 3 teams contributing to this project.
- Users will start up those forms and see in the container.
- Every pages use the same shared modules such as @angular, core-js, rxjs, zone.js etc.

With such an aplication, we desire all the team members to build and deploy each forms separately and individually when needed.
We also desire every team members to work on one of the related forms as if it is a different project.

I imagine we have below folder structure in live server. Is not really there any way to achieve that?

[Here is the deployed folder organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oab7j.jpg)

[Here is the project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYvHj.jpg)

After the development of `page-99` finishes I want to build & deploy itself only (as seen in the `Dist` folder).
After that, the main application will inject a service while loading that component.

Is that really possible with Angular 2?

Thank you all in advance for sharing your ideas and information with me.

Comment: did you managed to find a solution?

Comment: hi, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Angular elements might be helpful to achieve this functionality. I found this [blog](http://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/05/04/microservice-clients-with-web-components-using-angular-elements-dreams-of-the-near-future.aspx).
They also did the poc for this [project](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-microapp). To achieve this we need to use the angular 6 version.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post : [How to build and publish an Angular module](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464)
which describes the same problem and uses rollupjs(http://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) for build a module indirectly.

It is important to use rollupjs so that your software package does not include Angular